# No sound to single speaker, even after replacing the speaker

Tags: chevrolet, audio, wiring, aveo

I have a 2005 Chevy Aveo, and the front passenger speaker has no sound. I was able to find a replacement, and swapped out the original speaker for the spare. Unfortunately, this did not help. I know the replacement speaker works (I tested it before installing).

***The car has factory audio. What else can I check?***

Comment: The channel could be blow in the head unit.

Comment: How would I check for that, and what would it take to fix it?

Comment: Use a known good speaker (like the new one) and directly wire it from the head unit. Also, double check your new speaker to ensure it's good as well ... stranger things have happened.

Comment: Connect a small (1.5V) battery briefly to both terminals. You should hear a click.

Comment: Also, don't forget to check that your Pan and Fade controls aren't set to exclude that speaker.  I know it's unlikely but it is possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can take the speaker from the side that is functioning and test the other speaker wire with it.

- If the other speaker works, you know you need a new speaker.
- If the speaker doesn't work then you can check the wire at the radio.
- If you need to check the wire, you can turn on the radio and check the voltage at the wire (12volt) and see if you are getting any power there.
- if you are not getting power I would check the wire at the radio, which involves pulling it out of the dash maybe.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to DucatiKiller's answer, it's also possible that the wires between the radio and speaker have failed - most likely at the point they pass from the car to the door. You could test this by disconnecting the speaker wires from the back of the radio and checking for continuity between there and the end the speaker plugs in to.

A common symptom of this is an intermittently working speaker, but it can also result in total failure...